# broken blocks after Drupal 7 Windows to Linux migration

Tags: migrations

I'm in the process of migrating a Drupal 7 site from a development Windows box to a soon to be production Linux box.

The Linux box has all the required dependencies and is running the same version of PHP/mySql/Apache/Tomcat/Solr.

I've copied all of the files over and exported/imported the database.

The first time I went to the page, it loaded fine.  I get my superfish menu and my rotating banner.  However, after I goto a different (any) page, my superfish menu and rotating banner disappear.

I dropped the database and re-imported it, and got the same exact behavior.  First load is fine, subsequent visits the page is broken.

I thought it might be something to do with caching, so I cleared the cache and got the message:

```
The block Superfish 1 (Superfish) was assigned to the invalid region superfish and has been disabled.
The block View: Rotating Banner was assigned to the invalid region nivoslider and has been disabled.
```

I tried to export/import the database using the "Backup and Migrate" plugin... no change.

Is there anyway to fix this?  Anyplace I could start looking to see where it's falling apart?

Comment: Any errors on the admin reports status page?

Comment: Were you using a sub theme prior to the migration? Might be an idea to copy the .info file for your theme that contains the custom block regions....

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong It can't find the Solr server, which is a another issue I've been fighting.  I don't think (hope?) this is related.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your block regions? Sometimes when I migrate a site (though for me it's between servers running different OSs), blocks disappear from the site. However, it's just a matter of them getting thrown out of their regions, and the solution is to just go to Structure -> Blocks and put them back into their appropriate regions.

Comment: It is the regions themselves that are disappearing.  And only after certain writes to the database.

Comment: Oh, ok then. I thought it was just the blocks that were disappearing. Unfortunately that _has_ happened to me before, but my solution was to just re-migrate the site.